# How can I make a fixed CSS animation

Tags: css, css-animations

In this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3e5sqe36/1
I am trying to make a fixed position div use an animation, but applying the animation to the div pushes it off the top of the viewport.

I found this question: [How do I use CSS animations to slide a fixed position element from the bottom of the page to the top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931677/how-do-i-use-css-animations-to-slide-a-fixed-position-element-from-the-bottom-of)
and I tried applying the "bottom left" to the starting keyframe of the animation but that didn't seem to work for me either.

Here is the CSS code:

```
.animated { 
    -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: inifinite;
    animation-name: pulse;
    animation-duration: .1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
} 

@-webkit-keyframes pulse { 
    0% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); } 
    50% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.1); } 
    100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); } 
} 
@keyframes pulse { 
    0% { transform: scale(1); } 
    50% { transform: scale(1.1); } 
    100% { transform: scale(1); } 
} 
.pulse { 
    -webkit-animation-name: pulse; 
    animation-name: pulse; 
}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3e5sqe36/3/)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think to add the lines there, that helps a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your div is not in fixed position, is the img where you put it.

I do this:

· html

```
 <div class="animated pulse"><img class="imgInside" src="http://i.imgur.com/PTxTk6o.gif"></div>
```

· css

```
 .pulse { 
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse; 
  animation-name: pulse;
  position: fixed;
  left:5%; 
  bottom: 5%;
 }
 .imgInside {
  display: block;
  filter:drop-shadow(-10px 0px 3px #000); 
  -webkit-filter:drop-shadow(-10px 0px 3px #000); 
  width:100px;
  z-index: -2;
 }
```

I hope that help you